# How to create shared head memory exe and dll/shared Objects

Tags: c, memory, dll, shared-memory

I am creating a Cross Platform Shared Library in C. I know that there are lot of differences between Multiple OS/Hardware and chaos increased by adding each time new OS. To overcome the problem I decided to create a Shared Object. While creating the Shared Object Library I struck in the problem and after research found out that it is Shared Memory and Heap Memory problem.

Now I want to create a share Object Memory or Head Memory. So, that the same memory can be accessed by different EXE or another DLL/Shared Object Process. I have gone through many recommendations by searching web for Sharing Heap Memory and other things. Almost all the solutions are provided in C++. But I want it in C only. Kindly let me know how to share object memory in C so that a Object created by shared object can be used, destroyed or shared by exe.

Currently using CentOS 6 - GCC for Creating Shared Library and testing on Linux, Mac and Windows

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're using Windows, in which case you create shared memory using memory mapped files.

First, use [CreateFileMapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366537%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to create a memory mapped handle. By setting the first parameter of the API call to `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` you are telling Windows not to map an actual file into memory, but instead to create a region of shared memory. You can give the region a name so that other processes can open the region.

Once you've create the file mapping you then use [MapViewOfFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366761%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to map the shared region into your address space. This will give you back a pointer to the shared region, and you can then write directly to it.

If you're on Linux or MacOS then you'll want to use the [mmap](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) call with the `MAP_ANONYMOUS` and `MAP_SHARED` flags (I think).

Since there's no standard C API that works on all platforms you'll need to wrap the APIs and use some `#ifdef` magic to pick the right implementation.

Comment: Currently using CentOS 6 - GCC for Creating Shared Library and testing on Linux, Mac and Windows